# is there a Convert.ToSingle[,,]() method?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, byte

I'm saving my 3d array (neural network) in bytes using `System.Convert.ToByte()` is there a way to reverse this, when I want to load the array from a byte file?

Comment: Can you show the code to convert from array to byte.why are you converting to byte?

Comment: @viveknuna genes = System.Convert.ToByte(allDependencies);    I'm converting it to byte because from what I know, it takes up a lot less storage and I figured it would be easier to store as a file than an array would be

Comment: but it would be next to impossible to write it back to the array. just think about it how will it know the dimension of array?

Comment: My knowledge of bytes is next to nothing so I just assumed it is possible

Comment: what is signature of the array?

Comment: you mean this?: float[,,]

Comment: bytes aside, how would I go about storing it as an array? JSON? I feel like that would be quite challenging as right now I have a fixed amount of neurons but later I would like to have it based on the org's biology. I guess I could save it as a text file.

Comment: Use `BitConverter.ToSingle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). Convert array to json and store in file. I dont know the array declaration so you can change accordingly, I have used `int[,,]`.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr, Formatting.Indented);
int[,,] arrNew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[,,]>(json);
```